# How to navigate from a classic website (JS & HTML) to a React SPA, considering the Login is in React SPA?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, bootstrap-4

This is the case that I am trying to find a solution for:

I have a classic website that's written in HTML & JS (based on bootstrap). The user navigates through it and when the user decides to sign-in I need show the login modal dialog that's in React and if the login is successful then I need to load the react app. The react app is a full application with nav bar, etc. - that means the current site needs to be unloaded / disappear. (The URL could continue to be the same, no restriction; it's just that the first website is used for marketing and when the user signs-in I need to load the actual application).

How can I achieve this? I have been searching the internet for the last few hours but not solution so far.

This question is regarding JS & React integration has NOTHING TO DO WITH OAUTH. This is for moderators who don't understand coding.

Thanks in advance for any info that could help.

Comment: Why was this closed? It has all the details it needs and gets votes up.

Comment: BTW - I did find the solution after many hours and it's not documented anywhere but I will not post it here. I will go ahead to GitHub and post it there. Since, you try to undermine, this website, I cannot stay in front of your happiness. Let us move to GitHub, it's the future of any Dev Discussion and Dev Community anyway & let us not delay it. I'll close my account and stay on GH with all the discussions!

Answer (score 0):

It is the process.

I do not see any issue doing this in the same URL. In your solution, you can create two projects. setup startup page and then redirect to the original application, for security you should use O-Auth authentication. OAuth is explained [Here](https://oauth.net/articles/authentication/)

Comment: I am very familiar with O-Auth. That's is not the main problem. The problem is the loading of React from HTML portal. That's the part that I am looking. For example, if I have " <AppRender />, document.getElementById("ReactRoot") in the page, then the entire React App is loaded. I need to load only the Login page, and when auth is completed to ??? navigate to a new page that has only the ReactRoot element. That's the tricky part. Auth it's easy.